# LINQ and pagination

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We need to fetch data from a database using LINQ. We now need to implement pagination.

I suppose at a time we need to fetch `10` records at a time and when we click the Next button then it will fetch the next `10` records from db.

Please guide me with code. thanks

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I always use the following code:

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    //used by LINQ to SQL
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Page<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }

    //used by LINQ
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Page<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }

}
```

That is a static class,  which you can include in your sources.
After adding this class you can do the following:

```
MyQuery.Page(pageNumber, pageSize)
```

Comment: Please note that in LINQ to SQL you must first sort the input.

Comment: Useful as common extension method.

Comment: This only works if page 1 is your starting page. If you want to start with page number 0 for the first page, then remove the -1 from the page. And just do:
return source.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

Comment: this came very handy, thanks for posting the solution

Comment: @Sal your comment "Please note that in LINQ to SQL you must first sort the input"  seems interesting. Could you please describe this in depth. I'm keen to know the reason.

Comment: @AԃιƚყαGυɾαʋ This is why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437253/1458738

Answer (score 29):

The LINQ [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) function will limit how many items are taken. The [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) function will ignore the first n items. Something like this might work:

```
myDataSource.Skip(pageSize * curPage).Take(pageSize)
```

Comment: .Skip(pageSize * (curPage -1)).Take(pageSize) for a pager

Answer (score 16):

`.Skip` and `.Take` extension methods could be used:

```
var result = (from c in Customers
              select new 
              {
                  c.City,
                  c.ContactName
              }
              ).Skip(5).Take(5);
```