# How to implement pagination with group by using Entity Framework Core 3.0 without retrieving all rows?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.0

How would you implement pagination when the input data needs to be grouped first? I understand how to implement pagination from the link below:

[LINQ and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185159/linq-and-pagination)

, but I would like to be able to do this where each item in the paginated list is a group (that can be expanded) from the input data. Something similar to the code below - to prevent retrieving all rows of the table into memory, ordersList is `IQueryable`. The `IQueryable` returned is what I would like to pass into the pagination function.

```
from order in ordersList
group order by order.FullName into customers
select customers
```

However, a query like this runs on the client (and actually throws an exception in Entity Framework Core 3.0+). Is there a way to only retrieve the items on the current page for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve limited data and then group on the client side:

```cs
var keys = ordersList
   .Select(o => new {o.FullName})
   .Distinct()
   .OrderBy(о => o.FullName)
   .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
   .Take(pageSize);

var items =
   from order in ordersList
   join key in keys on order.FullName equals key.FullName
   select order;

var result = 
   from order in items.AsEnumerable()
   group order by order.FullName into customers
   select customers;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must **paginate** by group. You should use the `group number` instead of the `page number`.

```
//group sequence
int groupSeq = 1;

//select current group
var p = (from order in context.TBLGroups
       group order by order.FullName into customers
       select customers.Key).OrderBy(a => a).Skip(groupSeq - 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
       string FullName = p.ToString();

//get all items in current group
var items = (from order in context.TBLGroups
       where order.FullName == FullName
       select order).ToList();
```