# LINQ - Order By and Distinct by different fields. Skip & Take distinct values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm trying to `ORDER BY` some fields but `SELECT DISTINCT` by another field, and after that apply a `Skip & Take`

**Code:**

```
var result = entities.OrderBy(e => e.OrderField)
                     .Select(e => e.SelectField)
                     .Distinct()
                     .Skip(skip)
                     .Take(take)
                     .ToArray();
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.'

I understand the reason (the set is being changed between the ordering and the skipping) but can I work around this issue without querying the database more than once (edit: and not fetching more entities than its supposed to)?

**EDIT:**
I don't think there's an optimal solution for that, so what I did was fetch the values and then paginated them. *sigh*

```
var result = entities.OrderBy(e => e.OrderField)
                     .Select(e => e.SelectField)
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToArray()
                     .Skip(skip)
                     .Take(take)
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take from `Distinct` values from database and then work in memory like this:

```
var result = entities.OrderBy(e => e.OrderField)
                     .Select(e => e.SelectField)
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToArray()
                     .Skip(skip)
                     .Take(take)
                     .ToArray();
```

You will be querying once as you wanted

Comment: i edited the condition on the question.. im trying not to fetch all the entities and then applying the pagination.

Comment: If you have one zillion values after Distinct() and you want to skip(3) and Take(5), what a waste it would be to transfer all values to local memory!

Comment: @MatheusSimon edited my answer. Please tell if it will work. I am interested

Comment: @DVL it doesnt, i've given up finding an optimal solution for that... im now fetching the ids and then applying the pagination. it looks a little like that first code on your answer, but divided into 2 variables. thanks for the effort though.

Comment: the first code actually follows the same logic of what i had to do so i marked it... you can remove the other code if you'd like.

Comment: was facing same kind of problem some time ago and as I remember also did not find the good solution for that

Answer (score 2):

You should add `.OrderBy(e => e)` before `Skip`.

```
var result = entities.OrderBy(e => e.OrderField)
                 .Select(e => e.SelectField)
                 .Distinct()
                 .OrderBy(e => e)
                 .Skip(skip)
                 .Take(take)
                 .ToArray();
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437178/the-method-skip-is-only-supported-for-sorted-input-in-linq-to-entities/3437217)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Matheus Simon

Comment: i checked the sql generated, the second order by cancels the first one. its like the first one wasnt made. nice try though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Updated based on the comment. 
The following code should work in your case:

```
var result = entities
            .OrderBy(e => e.OrderField)
            .Select(e => e.SelectField)
            .GroupBy(e => e)
            .Select(group => group.Key)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Cant order by a property after selected another one, its another set.

Comment: @MatheusSimon sorry for not understanding your scenario properly in the first place. Please see the updated code. It will solve you problem.

Comment: its not grouping, nice try though

Comment: its throwing the exception. im going to make 2 queries and give up this solution. thanks hasan!